# Human survivors in a boat on a lake on some alien planet

Tags: story-identification, movie

I just today remembered a scene from a movie:

Two humans (maybe it was a male-female couple, not sure) fall with their capsule (I guess it, don't remember) on the strange alien planet. They get to some lake and use a rubber boat. They wonder is it possible that there is alien life in the lake. Later when they were in the boat on the lake, some glowing alien big fish, or let's say monster passed very near to their boat. That all happens in a dark, just like that night is always on that planet.

Except that the movie is not about those two and their survival, it's about something totally different; they get there by some accident I believe.

I can't say when I watched it. It was very long ago, on TV and not much more than 10 years I believe.

Comment: The darkness and the "glowing alien fish" really remind me of Europa Report. The astronauts don't use a rubber boat, though in the end the landing craft sinks into the sea of Europa. Are you sure about the boat?

Comment: I really don't know the Europa report, and just found it on youtube in full length.  Nothing looks similar to my memories, That's not it!